# Simple protobuf-net code snippet... benchmark de/serialize long[,] against Binaryformatter

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net, binaryformatter

How would the following (working...) .net c# snippet to de/serialize long[,] xlate to protobuf-net?

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;//.BinaryFormatter;
/*???using protobuf-net;//from protobuf-net r688.zip CoreOnly\mono\*/
....
public BinaryFormatter B=new BinaryFormatter();
public FileStream s;
public long[,]E=new long[10,4];
....
using(s=new FileStream(filnm,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write))B.Serialize(s,E);
....
using(s=new FileStream(filnm,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))E=long[,])B.Deserialize(s);
....
```

Comment: Well, protobuf doesn't have a concept of multj-dimensional or nested arrays, and protobuf-net (a specific protobuf implementation) doesn't choose to add anything out-of-spec for this scenario. So the first thing you'd need to consider is: how to store it in a way that serialised.

Comment: That's maybe how the question should've been put : how to 'quick and dirty' .Net base types using protobuf (and so benchmark them). .Net base types (if not mixed in same object) are by default [Serializable], that is the [Serializable] doesn't need to be explicitly coded...